# how to activate resize option in ui-layout-west

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a full page interface using the excellent jQuery UI Layout plugin. 
but unfortunately west side unable to resize with mouse which i have mentioned in below image. i am not able to find any solution for it.

Below is my code which i used:

```
<div class="ui-layout-west">
    <%@include file="abc.jsp"%>
</div>
```

Below is my sample image of west pane.

[image: Resize]

Comment: I gave a solution. does it solve your problem or you are looking for something different? @Mayur

Comment: it worked for me thanks @Md Salahuddin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, It looks like you have to include js for jquery ui. you can then set resizable option like below according to your need.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').layout({          
        applyDefaultStyles: true,
        resizable: true,
        east__resizable:false,
        north__resizable:false,
        south__resizable:false,        
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-south">South</div>
<div class="ui-layout-east">East</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
</body>
</html>
```